# Android FileObserver not working when copying files with MTP on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, mtp, fileobserver

I have a FileObserver observing ALL_EVENTS (for test purpose) on a folder in the external storage.

The FileObserver will trigger for any events originating from the tablet. For example, if my application or another application on the tablet creates a file in this folder, it works fine.

However, on the newer Marshmallow system, when copying files with MTP nothing is triggered. Same if I copy files with the shell. Everything used to work on our previous Lollipop system.

Any idea why this would happen?